# Reloading PHP FORM using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In my web portal, I have one page `index.php` which have `<div>` tag which content is obtained using `AJAX`. At this `<div>` tag the page `index2.php` is called. At the page `index2.php` there is one form which should be submitted using `AJAX` (without refreshing whole page, just refreshing `index2.php`). After submit, `index2.php` should be again called but with some additional arguments from form (over `POST`).

Problem is because `POST` request is sent, but it looks like content of `<div>` (`index2.php`) is not changed. Here is the code:

**index.php**

```
 <div id="left_side">
       <h3>Toolbar</h3>
 </div>

  <div id="content">
      there will be refreshed index2.php
  </div>
  ......
   function doAjax() {

          var frm = $('#plotForm1');
          $.ajax({
              type: frm.attr('method'),
              url: frm.attr('action'),
              data: frm.serialize(),
              success: function (data) {

                            }
             });    
     }
```

**index2.php**

```
<form id="plotForm1" action="index2.php" onsubmit='doAjax(); return false;' method="post">
 ....
</form>
```

Comment: why action is hcm_result.php ? did the ajax call change data in db? After changing , where is the code to reload data ?

Comment: It is mistake in typing code here, it should be index2.php. Dont ajax function automatically reload this page?

Comment: ajax can update db and  reload data  if you wrote that :-) automatically i dont know

Comment: How to reload page index2.php? :) I was not able to find function to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**index.php**

```
<div id="left_side">
       <h3>Toolbar</h3>
 </div>

  <div id="content">
      there will be refreshed index2.php
  </div>
  ......
   function doAjax() {

          var frm = $('#plotForm1');
          $.ajax({
              type: frm.attr('method'),
              url: frm.attr('action'),
              data: frm.serialize(),
              success: function (data) {

$('#content').html(data);

                            }
             });    
     }
```

**index2.php**

```
<form id="plotForm1" action="index2.php" onsubmit='doAjax(); return false;' method="post">
 ....
</form>
```